# Connecting python with sql server 2012

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I got the following error message when trying to test my python connection with sql server:

> TypeError: 'pyodbc.Connection' object is not callable.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks.

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL Server Native client 11.0}',
                  server = 'XXXX-PC', database = 'MYDATABASE')
def main():
        cursor = conn()
        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE production (product_ID int, product_Name varchar')
        cursor.execute('SELECT* FROM production')
        return cursor.fetchall
        cursor.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
```

Comment: you can take a look here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sqlalchemy/2mFulgsjiZ8

Comment: Hi gpicchiarelli, i did as instructed in the article:                                                                def conn():
             return pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver ... but I got the following syntax error: ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'varchar'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: Its an sql syntax error, I'll need to adjust my sql query.

Comment: This is correct. Since it is a varchar, you have to specify how many characters it can be total.

Answer (score 0):

The error might be caused by this line:

```
    cursor = conn()
```

it should be changed to

```
    cursor = conn.cursor()
```

`conn` is not a method to call which is why you get the error.  See the example for *Connect to a Database* within the [pyodbc's GettingStarted](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted) docs.

---

In addition the line

```
    return cursor.fetchall
```

should be changed to:

```
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

`fetchall` is a method so it needs the `()`.

---

Also, not sure why you are returning from `def main()` before calling `cursor.close()`.  It will never be called. Perhaps set the results of `fetchall()` to a variable, call `close()`, and then return the results.  For example:

```
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return results
```

Or do you even need to return anything if you are simply just testing the connection and not doing anything with the resuts:

```
    cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return
```